# MathLive fraction has a white hover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the MathLive library for js, for making a math website. The library is really good, but it has a big problem, when I'm writing a fraction there is white rectangle over it, and I can't even see what I'm writing, there is any way to remove it?

I already tried to set some css for some MathLive classes, but it didn't work.

```
    .ML__fraction > .ML__fence::before,
    .ML__fraction > .ML__fence::after {
      background: none !important;
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    .ML__contains-highlight
    {
       display: none !important;
       background: none !important;
    }
```

I put together a minimal reproducible example, when I click on the fraction and I write something in it, the white rectangle is placed over it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculus</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        #math-input
        {
            border: 1px solid aliceblue;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px;
            color: aliceblue;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive.css">
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/mathlive"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
    <section>
        <br>
        <br>
        <math-field id="math-input" class="bg-dark">
            \frac{\placeholder{}}{\placeholder{}}
        </math-field>
    </section>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.0/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const mathInput = document.getElementById('math-input');

        mathInput.addEventListener('input',() => {
            const value = mathInput.value;
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put together a [mre] and include it in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just did as you said